# How to add google analytics in chrome extension with manifest 3

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In Manifest v2 I was using GA - was working great. But with V3

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-30398300-16']);
_gaq.push(['_setCampSourceKey', 'chrome-extension']);    // source

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

not working inside background script